# c++ ignore front spaces when comparing strings eg: "str1"compare.(" str2") = TRUE

Tags: c++, string, char, compare

Hi I was wondering what is the shortest way to make string str1 seem equal to string str2

```
str1 = "Front Space";
str2 = " Front Space";

/*Here is where I'm missing some code to make the strings equal*/

if (str1.compare(str2) == 0) { // They match 
    cout << "success!!!!" << endl; // This is the output I want
}
```

All I need it for str1 to equal str2
How can I do it?

I have made multiple attempts but they all don't seem to work correctly. I think it's because of the number of characters in the string, ie: str1 has less characters than str2.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= str1.length() + 1; i++){
    str1[str1.length() - i ] = str1[str1.length() - (i + 1)];
}
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 6):

If you can use Boost, trim functions are available in *boost/algorithm/string.hpp*

```
str1 = "Front Space";
str2 = " Front Space";
boost::trim_left( str2 ); // removes leading whitespace

if( str1 == str2 ) {
  // ...
}
```

Similarly, there's `trim` that removes both leading and trailing whitespace. And all these functions have `*_copy` counterparts that return a trimmed string instead of modifying the original.

---

If you cannot use Boost, it's not hard to create your own `trim_left` function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void trim_left( std::string& s )
{
  auto it = s.begin(), ite = s.end();

  while( ( it != ite ) && std::isspace( *it ) ) {
    ++it;
  }
  s.erase( s.begin(), it );
}

int main()
{
  std::string s1( "Hello, World" ), s2( " \n\tHello,   World" );

  trim_left( s1 ); trim_left( s2 );

  std::cout << s1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World
Hello,   World
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can use `boost`. If you don't want to use `boost`, or you can't (maybe because it's homework), it is easy to make an ltrim function.

```
string ltrim(string str)
{
    string new_str;
    size_t index = 0;

    while (index < str.size())
    {
        if (isspace(str[index]))
            index++;
        else
            break;
    }

    if (index < str.size())
        new_str = str.substr(index);

    return new_str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LLVM also has some trim member functions for their [StringRef](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html#a44b1141e695b117bb36a77961883893d) class.  This works without modifying your string and without making copies, in case that's important to you.

```
llvm::StringRef ref1(str1), ref2(str2);
ref1.ltrim();
ref2.ltrim();
if (ref1 == ref2) {
    // match
}
```